# How to set parent component state from child of child

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to finish this web challenge to land an Internship interview, and I have this problem with my code :

My webapp is a page that contains 4 main components :
- ProfilePage: Parent of all
    - UserPanel : A side bar that shows user data via request to api
    -TabBar : A container next to side bar that contains 2 components :
         -> EventsTab : Shows events related to current user (same as the one displayed on user pane )
         -> FriendsTab : Show friends of the current user (contains 
"Fetch query={this.props.query} action={this.props.action}/")
-> Fetch : The component receives which call to make to the API through its query prop. It also calls the proper handler function explained below to handle different calls ( events, friends, userpanel )

My approach after a good amount of research and some coffee, was to Lift all the states Up to my ProfilePage Container, and I am now able to display user data in the UserPanel component, 
I am using a handler to call a function getChildUser(user) with the user being the axios response.data directly from the Fetch Component, thus, getting the response from Fetch .
To give you a better idea, here is an example of a "/api/players/4" GET Response :

```
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Foo",
"last_name": "Bar",
"company": "Martin, Hi and Dumont",
"city_name": "Andreberg",
"last_seen": "2018-10-08T12:23:13.687Z",
"picture": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rawdiggie                                     /128.jpg",
"total_events": 93,
"total_friends": 83
}
```

And the handler :

```
     this.getChildUser = this.getChildUser.bind(this);
     this.getFriendsList = this.getFriendsList.bind(this);

    //...
    getChildUser(user) {
      this.setState({
        user: {
           playername: user.first_name + " " + user.last_name,
           picture: user.picture,
           city: user.city_name,
           last_seen: user.last_seen,
           events: user.total_events,
           friends: user.total_friends,
           company: user.company
           }
      });
    }
```

This Handler is called on the "UserPanel query="/players/5/" action={this.getChildUser}" inside of ProfilePage where we have "Fetch query={this.props.query} action={this.props.action} ", then we display the player data :

```
      //.
      <Card.Title> {this.props.user.events} </Card.Title>
      //.
```

Finally, on our 'Fetch' :

```
     axios
    .get(API + "/" + this.props.query)
    .then(response => this.props.action(response.data));
```

Now the I did the same thing to get using the same Fetch component, to retrieve the list of friends, but I just can't manage to get it working, i figured it has something to do with the formatting of the response because the friends response is as follows :
When calling "/api/friends/5"

```
 [
          {
          "id": 18508,
        "first_name": "Elisa",
      "last_name": "Caron",
        "company": "Carre, Rolland and Rodriguez",
        "city_name": "West Louisshire",
       "last_seen": "2017-11-14T09:31:52.026Z",
         "picture": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/skkirilov/128.jpg",
        "total_events": 193,
        "total_friends": 25
  },
  {
"id": 92653,
"first_name": "Louis",
"last_name": "Bertrand",
"company": "Nicolas, Faure and Lemaire",
"city_name": "Port Ambretown",
"last_seen": "2018-06-22T11:14:12.862Z",
"picture": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/taybenlor/128.jpg",
"total_events": 113,
"total_friends": 135
 }
]
```

I tried using this handler: in this case the name is getFriendsList
I realize it's a nested object field, but I couldn't figure out a way to fix it.

```
    getFriendsList(friendsList){
       this.setState({
            friendsList : [
                       user: {
                       playername: friendsList.user.first_name + " " + friendsList.last_name,
                       picture: friendsList.user.picture,
                       events: friendsList.user.total_events,
                       friends: friendsList.user.total_friends,
                       },
               ]
        })
     }
```

This time we pull then info from "Fetch" by calling getFriendsList(response.data) trough our "FriendsTab" component then "TabBar" then back to "ProfilePage"

I get the error : _this.props.friendsList

" TypeError: _this.props.friendsList is undefined " in my component

Thank you !

I tried transforming the json response from the "Fetch" into an array, changing the friendsList structure ( though I'm not sure I've done it right )

Here is my github repository if you want to look it up more in detail
https://gitlab.com/mRamzi/mybchallenge

EDIT:

I can confirm that the problem comes from axios not correctly puttin data in my state, using react dev tools I noticed that props are passed but still empty, the getFriendsList() did not do it work, still trying to solve it

Comment: Although you've added plenty of code, there's no place where you try to use `this.props.friendsList`.  There may be a stack trace associated with that error or maybe you can search your codebase and show us where that occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @larz , indeed there was too much code to copy, i edited and posted my gitlab repo url if you want to help investigate, my hopes are turning to redux now..

Comment: create a top function handleSet() and pass down onSet={handleSet} and next onSet={this.props.onSet}... you don't need (and can't) access the parent.parent, you can call directly a function from that parent if you pass down

Comment: @JoazitoPolo that is basically what i did, I think the problem comes from my json response from axios not being retrieved corretcly trough the getFriendsList() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the problem, I will just go ahead and give the details in case someone faces the same issue:

The issue was indeed caused by the formatting of my json response (axios's response.data) that contained nested objects, i had to map over the friendsList and get the values.